# Need Help in Configuring Links React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to configure links of the below nested navigation. I wanted to navigate user to bdetails or adetails or alist or blist views based on data that comes from firebase notification.

```
const AStack = () => <Stack.Navigator>
<Stack.Screen name="adetails" component={ADetails} />
<Stack.Screen name="alist" component={AList} />
</Stack.Navigator>

const BStack = () => <Stack.Navigator>
<Stack.Screen name="bdetails" component={BDetails} />
<Stack.Screen name="blist" component={BList} />
</Stack.Navigator>

const TabNavigation = () => <Tab.Navigator>
<Tab.Screen name="A" component={AStack} />
<Tab.Screen name="B" component={BStack} />
</Tab.Navigator>


const TabNavContainer = () => <Stack.Navigator>
<Stack.Screen name="app" component={TabNavigation} />
</ Stack.Navigator>

const RootNav = () => <Drawer.Navigator>
<Drawer.Screen name="tabnav" component={TabNavContainer} />
</Drawer.Navigator>

const linking = {
    prefixes: ['cdpharmacy://'],
    config: {
      screens: {
        RootNav: {
          path: 'root',
          screens: {
            tabnav: {
              path: 'nav',
              screens: {
                app: {
                  path: 'app',
                  screens: {
                    A: {
                      path: 'a',
                      screens: {
                        alist: 'list/:param1',
                        adetails: 'details/:param1/:param2'
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

<NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="AuthNav" />
          <Stack.Screen name="RootNav"/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

The below link is not working in the app.

```
linkTo('/root/nav/app/a/details/param1/param2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use deeplinking for that simply check notification data in App.js when recieved in setBackgroundMessageHandler() if data equal to something navigate to that page.

See in this e.g. if my data.action== "open_map" im navigating user to RouteMap page.
e.g.

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
    const {data} = remoteMessage;
    if (data.action == 'open_map') {
      navigate('RouteMap', {data: data.eventsteamID});
    } else if (data.action == 'open_home') {
      navigate('Home');
    } else {
      console.log('Something went wrong.');
    }
    console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
  });
```